# Missing Desktop Icon Labels in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

My desktop icons have been stripped of their icon labels, and nothing seems to be recovering them. To be clear, when I attempt to rename, the text shows up, and when I view my desktop in an explorer window, all text is preserved.

System restore to a stock state will not recover. No changes have been done to the computer -- no installs or downloads for two weeks prior to this error. Rebuilt the icon cache, still no response.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit
- Profile: Local, non-roaming

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Method 1:**  I would suggest you to I
>   would suggest you to perform an SFC
>   scan and then check- Perform a SFC
>   Scan
>
> 1. Click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories,
>      right-click Command Prompt, and then
>      click Run as administrator. If you are
>      prompted for an administrator password
>      or for a confirmation, type the
>      password, or click Allow
> 2. Type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>
> sfc /scannow
>
> A message will appear stating that
>   'The system scan will begin'. Be
>   patient because the scan may take some
>   time
>
> 3. If any files require a replace SFC will replace them. You may be
>      asked to insert your Win7 DVD for this
>      process to continue
> 4. If everything is okay you should, after the scan, see the
>      following message "Windows resource
>      protection did not find any integrity
>      violations"
> 5. After the scan has completed, close the command prompt window,
>      restart the computer and check.
>
> Check the below mentioned link for
>   further guidance on SFC scan
>   -http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833
>
> **Method 2:**  if the issue persists, I
>   would suggest you to refer to the
>   below mentioned link to fix a
>   corrupted user profile and follow the
>   steps provided-
>   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Fix-a-corrupted-user-profile
>
> For additional assistance you nay
>   refer to the link - Create a new user
>   account-
>   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/Windows7/Create-a-user-account
>
> Check if the issue appears in the new
>   user account. You may also check after
>   logging in as an administrator.
>
> **Method 3:**  If the hotfix you have
>   installed is not very critical for
>   your computer then you may use the
>   below mentioned steps for system
>   restore -
>
> The System Restore tool uses restore
>   points to return system files and
>   settings to an earlier point in time.
>   You can use it to restore the
>   operating system to a point in time in
>   which you did not experience the
>   issue.
>
> Note: When you use System restore to
>   restore the computer to a previous
>   state, programs and updates that you
>   installed are removed. It is possible
>   that your hotfix files may get
>   removed.
>
> To do this, there must be a System
>   Restore point at which the logon was
>   successful. Follow the steps mentioned
>   below to perform system restore – To
>   restore the operating system to an
>   earlier point in time, follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, type system restore in the Start Search box, and
>      then click System Restore in the
>      Programs list. If you are prompted for
>      an administrator password or
>      confirmation, type your password or
>      click Continue.
> 2. In the System Restore dialog box, click Choose a different restore
>      point, and then click next.
> 3. In the list of restore points, click a restore point that was created
>      before you began to experience the
>      issue, and then click next.
> 4. Click Finish. The computer restarts, and the system files and
>      settings are returned to the state
>      that they were in at the time that the
>      restore point was created.

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/w7desktop/thread/d5fc0cc2-8082-4dc3-b39e-1f4924a6f1bd

Comment: Anytime man....

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, problems are persistent in safe-mode and when running SFC /scannow it blue screens the machine, system restore fails, have checked the disks for errors and memory, it's deffinately a windows issue, have tried pretty much everything and still no luck, next step is to run SFC from the repair cd and see how that pans out, will keep you posted!

Comment: It worked, note to those trying to run sfc /scannow from safemode, do it from the recovery CD instead! :)